# If normal distribution can be adapted to the set of data?

Tags: matlab

Using Matlab I need to generate a sample `x` of random numbers (n=30) from the normal distribution, using the command `normrnd`, and then check whether the normal distribution can be adapted to the sample.

I used the Matlab function `chi2gof` which gives a result `h = 0` which means that `x´ is a sample from the normal distribution. But when the size of the sample is small (n=30) that result doesn't mean much. How could I answer this question when the sample is small?

```
x = normrnd(50, 2, 30, 1)
h = chi2gof(x)
h =

     0
```

Answer (score 1):

Matlab's *Statistics Toolbox* contains a number of other tests for normality, including the [Anderson–Darling](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/adtest.html), [Jarque–Bera](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/jbtest.html), and [Lilliefors](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/lillietest.html) tests. The latter appears to be particularly adapted for use with small samples. The Matlab implementation contains tables of critical values which are more precise than those provided by [Lilliefors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lilliefors_test) himself and may be made even more precise by running a Monte–Carlo simulation tailored to the given data set.